# is there a way to override the transition inside a vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

i was wondering if there is a way to override or change transition inside a vue component .
I am actually using **buefy** components to make my website.. but the problem is that some components like collapse it has a slot which has fade transition and i dont like it.

I was windering if there is a way to override vue transition 
or make a **mixin** which will override javascript **transition hooks.**. but now the problem is that they are applying css transition.. instead and i want the javascript hooks to fire and make a slide transition some how..

instead of going to make  new vue component

Comment: Have you tried anything? any research or code or something else?

Comment: Try `<b-collapse animation="slide">` Does that work?

Comment: @Manishh yeah already searched a'lot but could't find anything helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buefy seems to support normal Vue style transitions on its components, though it is undocumented.  The buefy css reveals a few predefined fade, zoom-in, zoom-out, slide-next, and slide-previous transitions.  If you want different transitions you will have to define them yourself or use a css library like Animate.css.

You can override the default fade transition by adding the `animation="name"` to the components.

```
<b-collapse animation="slide-next">
  //..
</b-collapse>
```

You can create your own using css.

Example for custom animation '.myCustomSlide'

```
.myCustomSlide-leave-active,
.myCustomSlide-enter-active {
   transition: 1s;
}
.myCustomSlide-enter {
   transform: translate(100%, 0);
}
.myCustomSlide-leave-to {
   transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

Here is a working jfiddle example with two built in and one custom example.  https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/nnbup5wg/3/

Comment: Though i want to do something else but thanks for the answer.
i want to do a  height 0px and then full height transition.. which can not be possible with css

Comment: i want to make a slide-up down effect like **height : 0 ** on close and full height on open... for which i have to calculate height of container element dynamicly. so it is not posiable with css . i was wondering is there a way to add javascript transition hooks afterwords

Comment: what i tried is  i a make a separate slide-transition component which is working just fine when i use it on normal html elements but .. when i used it inside the <b-collapse></b-collapse>  it didnt' worked out